# Download file with firefox bypassing popup : Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am using selenium with python to download certain files from this [web page](http://www.oceanenergyireland.com/testfacility/corkharbour/observations). I have been previously using set preferences to create Firefox profile, and they worked perfectly fine. In this case the download pop up opens on same page, despite given preferences it always opens pop up for action (save/open). can anybody help bypassing it and download file automatically without pop up alert ?

The preference settings are:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir)
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")


        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

File i am trying to download:
[image: File to be downloaded]

Thank you, beside if full code is required is mentioned below:

```
# -*- coding utf-8 -*-
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import shutil
import uuid

class crawlOcean():

    def __init__(self):
        print("hurray33")
        global downloadDir
        downloadDir = ""

        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir)
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                          "text/plain, application/octet-stream, application/binary, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, text/comma-separated-values, text/xml, application/xml")
        fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
        #self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        print("hurray")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        self.driver.get("http://www.oceanenergyireland.com/testfacility/corkharbour/observations")
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def crawl(self):
        print("see")
        driver = self.driver
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 600)")
        index = 0
        driver.switch_to.frame(index)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='CorkTideHeight']/div[3]/button[2]").click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='CorkTideHeight']/div[3]/div/ul/li[5]").click()
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = crawlOcean()
    obj.crawl()
```

Comment: Which file do you want to download? Precisely which element are you trying to click on?

Comment: @DebanjanB i have added image in the question, you see it by retrieving the url from code or [Click here](http://www.oceanenergyireland.com/testfacility/corkharbour/observations)

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate question of (now deleted) [Selenium Python: Unable to locate button ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906219/selenium-python-unable-to-locate-button-id) for which you have published an answer before?

Comment: @DebanjanB No, its not this question is about set preferences of Firefox, please see the description

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `text/csv`. Try `attachment/csv`, it is working. Actually this download file is generated in javascript itself and they have set custom data type like this.

```
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir)
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "attachment/csv")
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```